# monotone convergence of an Integral

Tags: integration, measure-theory, logarithms, borel-measures

I am currently working on the following task

Let $f \in \mathcal{M_+}(\mathbb{R},\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ an $\mu$ is a borel-measure on $\mathbb{R}.$ Show that,

$$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-\infty}^\infty log{\left(1 + \frac{1}nf\right)}  \ \ \ d\mu \ = \ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f \ d\mu. $$

- We defined $\mathcal{M_+}(\mathbb{R},\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ as the set of measurable maps $f:\mathbb{R} \to [0,\infty].$
- because $f \in \mathcal{M_+}(\mathbb{R},\overline{\mathbb{R}})$ there exist a sequence of functions $({f_n})_n \subset \mathcal{M_o}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ with $0\le f_n \uparrow f$

  - we defined $\mathcal{M_o}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$ as the set of step functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Step functions are borel-measurable and have the shape of $\sum_{i=1}^{m} c_i \mathcal{X}A_i$

How do I start with the task? I would appreciate a hint or a little help.

What bothers me is the upper and lower limits of the integral.
Do I need to change the upper and lower limits? If yes, how I can do that?

To the right side of the equation I am not sure if I should construct a certain f to $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-\infty}^\infty log{\left(1 + \frac{1}nf\right)}$.

Can I replace the f on the left side of the equation with a sequence of functions $(f_n)_n$.
If so, what is the advantage of doing this?

kind regards,

WomBud

Comment: $(1+\frac f n)^{n}$ increases to $e^{f}$ as $n \to \infty$. Take logarithm and apply Monotone Convergence Theorem.

Comment: thank you for your hint :). From this I have calculated:

$\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-\infty}^\infty log{\left(1 + \frac{f}n\right)}  \ \ \ d\mu \ \ = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty n\  log{\left(1 + \frac{f}n\right)} \ \ d\mu$ = $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \  log{\left((1 + \frac{f}n\right)^n)} \ \ d\mu$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \log{\left((1 + \frac{f_n}n\right)^n)} \ \ d\mu$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty log(e^f) d\mu$ = $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f d\mu.$

Did I do that right?

Comment: Yes, it is right.